# Finding duplicates in multiple HUGE lists in Python (compare 2, 3, 4, 5 lists)

Tags: python, list, nlp, set

So I'm currently working on 5 dictionaries and very possibly more in the futur, with at least 257000+ entries each. Consider them as 5 huge text files(size: 10-20 Mb) with, say, 10-30 characters each line would be fine.
An example of an entry be like:

```
abaissements volontaires,abaissement volontaire.N+NA:mp
```

My mission is to find out duplicate words between/among different dictionaires.
So first of all, I have to process the file to get, for example, only ***abaissements volontaires*** from the example. After this part, my idea is to have a list that contains elements like:

```
dict_word_list = [[dict_A, [word1, word2, ...]], [dict_B, [word1, word2, ...]]]
```

The choice of lists over dicts is simply because dicts are unordered in Python and I have to know the name of the corresponding dictionary of each word list, so I put the corresponding dictionary names in element 0 of each list.

My question is how to find out duplicates between/among these huge lists and at the same time keep dictionary names? 
I tried ***if not in list*** but due to the file size and a very old processor(an intel core i3 in an old shabby laptop at work and I cannot use my own laptop due to confidentiality issues) , the program simply bugs there.

Maybe ***set*** would be a solution, but how do I shuffle the comparison? I would like to have results like:

> Duplicates dict_A, dict_B: [word1, word2, word3, ...]
>
> Duplicates dict_B, dict_C: [word1, word2, word3, ...]
>
> Duplicates dict_A, dict_B, dict_C: [word1, word2, word3, ...]

Comment: Can you sort the files first? Does that make it easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets are a very good approach. You could do something like this:

```
dict_1 = {1, 2 ,3}
dict_2 = {2, 3, 4}
dict_3 = {3, 4, 5}
dict_1 & dict_2
{2, 3}
dict_1 & dict_2 & dict_3
{3}
```

From the docs:

> s & t -    new set with elements common to s and t

Comment: I think I'm going to test ***from itertools import combinations*** to get different combinations and use ***set*** to see if the performance is still fine. :)

Comment: Post results when you finish testing :)

Comment: The performance of sets is way better than lists. I got what I wanted, thanks!